# Need help refactoring to use .where clause - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, where-clause

I have the following code which is legacy code and I need to refactor it to `.where` clauses but I'm having issues in refactoring it and the best way to do it.

Here is the code

```rb
# legacy
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction.legacy_find(
        :all,
        :include => [:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type],
        :conditions => ["dr_account_id = ?", @customer.id],
        :order => 'financial_transactions.id desc',
        :limit => 20)

# refactor attempt
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction.where(dr_account_id: @dr_account_id, customer: @customer.id).order('financial_transactions.id desc').limit(20)

# legacy
contact_or = ''
contact_or = ' OR contact_id IN(?) ' if  @customer.contacts.present?

@customer_complaints = Event.legacy_find(:all, { :order => 'id desc', :limit => 10, :conditions => ["complaint is true and (customer_account_id = ? #{contact_or} )", @customer.id].push_if(@customer.contacts.to_a.map(&:id), @customer.contacts.present?) })

# refactor attempt
@customer_complaints = Event.where(complaints: true, customer_account_id: [@customer_account_id], customer: @customer.id).order('id desc').limit(10)
```

Any help would be appreciated

**edit some methods that might be help in understanding the legacy_find**

```rb
def self.legacy_find(type, args=nil)
  # need to add capability to handle array of id's
  if type.kind_in?([Numeric, String, Array]) && !args
    result =  self.find(type)
  elsif !args
    result =  self.send(type.to_s)
  else
    result = self

    if type.kind_of?(Array)
      if !args[:conditions]
         args[:conditions] = ["1 = 1"]
      elsif args[:conditions].kind_of?(String)
        args[:conditions] = [args[:conditions]]
      end

      args[:conditions][0] = '(' + args[:conditions][0] + ')'

      args[:conditions][0] += " AND `" + self.table_name + "`.`id` in(" + type.join(',') + ")"
    elsif type && !type.kind_of?(Symbol)
      if !args[:conditions]
         args[:conditions] = ["1 = 1"]
      elsif args[:conditions].kind_of?(String)
        args[:conditions] = [args[:conditions]]
      end

      args[:conditions][0] = '(' + args[:conditions][0] + ')'

      args[:conditions][0] += " AND `" + self.table_name + "`.`id` = ?"
      args[:conditions].push(type)
    end

    result      = self.legacy_conditions(args)

    if type && ((type.kind_of?(String) && type.to_i.to_s == type) || type.kind_of?(Numeric))
      result = result.first
    elsif type && !type.kind_of?(Symbol)
      result = result.to_a
    else
      result =  type ? result.send((type == :all ? 'to_a' : type).to_s) : result
    end
  end

  new_result = result

  return new_result
end

def self.legacy_count(args=nil)
  new_result        = self.legacy_conditions(args).count
end

def self.legacy_sum(col, args=nil)
  new_result        = self.legacy_conditions(args).sum(col.to_s)
end

def self.legacy_conditions(args)
  return self if !args

  args[:conditions] = [] if args[:conditions] && args[:conditions][0].kind_of?(String) && args[:conditions][0].size == 0

  result = self
  result = result.where(args[:conditions]) if (args.has_key?(:conditions) && args[:conditions] && args[:conditions].size > 0)
  result = result.select(args[:select]) if args.has_key?(:select) && args[:select]
  result = result.includes(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
  result = result.includes(args[:include_without_references]) if args.has_key?(:include_without_references) && args[:include_without_references]
  result = result.references(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
  result = result.joins(args[:joins]) if args.has_key?(:joins) && args[:joins]
  result = result.order(args[:order]) if args.has_key?(:order) && args[:order]
  result = result.group(args[:group]) if args.has_key?(:group) && args[:group]
  result = result.limit(args[:limit]) if args.has_key?(:limit) && args[:limit]
  result = result.offset(args[:offset]) if args.has_key?(:offset) && args[:offset]
  result = result.from(args[:from]) if args.has_key?(:from) && args[:from]
  result = result.lock(args[:lock]) if args.has_key?(:lock) && args[:lock]
  result = result.readonly(args[:readonly]) if args.has_key?(:readonly) && args[:readonly]
  result
end
```

Honestly why this code exists is beyond me so I'm trying to phase it out.

**edit 2**
Based on the answers below I've come up with the following

```rb
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction
  .includes(:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type)
  .where(dr_account_id: @dr_account_id)
  .order(id: :desc)
  .limit(20)

@credit_transactions = FinancialTransaction
  .includes(:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type)
  .where(cr_account_id: @cr_account_id)
  .order(id: :desc)
  .limit(20)

contact_or = ''
contact_or = ' OR contact_id IN(?) ' if  @customer.contacts.size > 0

@customer_complaints = Event.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id, complaint: true).order(id: :desc).limit(10).or(Event.where(contact_id: @customer.contacts)) if @customer.contacts.present?
@customer_leads = Event.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id, lead: true).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_quotes = SalesQuote.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).or(SalesQuote.where(contact_id: @contact_id)).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_orders = SalesOrder.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_invoices = Invoice.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_credits = CreditNote.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_opportunities = Opportunity.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).or(Opportunity.where(contact_id: @contact_id)).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_estimates = Estimate.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).or(Estimate.where(contact_id: @contact_id)).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@customer_support_tickets = SupportTicket.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
@financial_matching_sets = FinancialMatchingSet.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id).order(id: :desc).limit(10)
```

However, I'm getting the following

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'sales_orders.customer_account_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `sales_orders`.* FROM `sales_orders` WHERE `sales_orders`.`customer_account_id` IS NULL ORDER BY `sales_orders`.`id` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma rails 5.0.3

Comment: What's `legacy_find`?

Comment: I'll update the question, but basically, this is a legacy system with a lot of weirdness including the legacy methods, seems to be that who wrote it decided to extend the `where` functionality, honestly not entirely sure, either way, I need to move it to a standardise and proper where statement because I'm getting MySQL errors all over the place

Comment: @SebastianPalma question updated

Comment: Ouch I really feel for you having to clean this "clever" code up. I'm having a hard time actually following any of this code - It might be easier to just look at the SQL queries generated and work from there. It looks somewhat like a wildly misguided attempt at porting Rails 2 style queries instead of actually just rewriting them.

Comment: Yeah, you can say that again @max haha it's going to take a while to refactor the entire app given some of the stuff I see but has to be done to get it to a normal ROR/best practice way because currently, it isn't it haha I just spent 75+ hours over a few weeks putting in proper routes as everything was handled through one match route. But I'll try your suggestion and see where I go.

Comment: @max The `customer_account_id` is a column of the `events` table, not the `sales_orders` table. It looks like you've copy+pasted a solution into a context where it doesn't belong.

Comment: Oops that's embarrassing haha, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query is relatively straight forward:

```
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction
 # you missed the includes
 .includes(
    :project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, 
    :credit_account, :transaction_type
  )
  .where(
    dr_account_id: @dr_account_id.id,
  )
  .order(id: :desc)
  .limit(20)
```

Then second query is a bit tougher.

You can create a `WHERE x IN (...)` clause simply by passing an array:

```
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction.where(
  id: [1,2,3]
)
```

You can also create a `WHERE x IN (subquery)` by passing a `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
Event.where(contact_id: @customer.contacts)
```

This is far more effective them using `.map(:id)` or `.ids` as you remove a full round trip to the DB.

Support for `OR` was added in Rails 5:

```
scope = Event.where(customer_account_id: @customer_id)
scope = scope.or(Event.where(contact_id: @customer.contacts)) if @customer.contacts.present?
```

So altogether it would look something like:

```
scope = Event.where(
  customer_account_id: @customer_id
  complaint: true
).order('id desc')
.limit(10)
scope = scope.or(Event.where(contact_id: @customer.contacts)) if @customer.contacts.present?
```

Comment: Hopefully this answer will be useful and lead you to a solution. Its hard to give an exact answer here since I don't know what SQL the legacy code generated and there is no spec/test that shows what the behavior should be.  I also couldn't find an answer to exactly when the `.or` query method was introduced.

Comment: `.or` was added to Rails 5.0: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b0b37942d729b6bdcd2e3178eda7fa1de203b3d0

Comment: I've added another update to the question @max

Answer (score 4):

> the best way to do it.

I don't have a concrete answer to this, but there's a few things you could try, such as:

- Write test cases for the **behaviour** of the old implementation, thus ensuring that they still **behave** the same with the new implementation. (Maybe you already have some such tests in place??!!)
- Write test cases for the **implementation** of the old vs new code, by checking `query.to_sql` remains unchanged?!
- Try running both versions on production, in parallel, assuming you have good error logging. For example, could you gradually switch over 10% of users to use the "new" implementations, thus catching any errors without causing mass failures for everyone?

But anyway... Aside from the pain of actually rewriting all of these in a safe/robust/well-tested way:

---

**First query:**

```
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction.legacy_find(
        :all,
        :include => [:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type],
        :conditions => ["dr_account_id = ?", @customer.id],
        :order => 'financial_transactions.id desc',
        :limit => 20)

# refactor attempt
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction
  .where(dr_account_id: @dr_account_id, customer: @customer.id)
  .order('financial_transactions.id desc')
  .limit(20)
```

This refactor ignores the `include` parameters. The legacy method says:

```
# ...
result = result.includes(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
result = result.references(args[:include]) if args.has_key?(:include) && args[:include]
# ...
```

So, your version should have been:

```
@debit_transactions = FinancialTransaction
  .includes([:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type])
  .references([:project, :department, :stock, :debit_account, :credit_account, :transaction_type])
  .where(dr_account_id: @dr_account_id, customer: @customer.id)
  .order('financial_transactions.id desc')
  .limit(20)
```

---

**Second query:**

```
# legacy
contact_or = ''
contact_or = ' OR contact_id IN(?) ' if  @customer.contacts.present?

@customer_complaints = Event.legacy_find(
  :all,
  :order => 'id desc',
  :limit => 10,
  :conditions => ["complaint is true and (customer_account_id = ? #{contact_or} )", @customer.id].push_if(@customer.contacts.to_a.map(&:id), @customer.contacts.present?)
)

# refactor attempt
@customer_complaints = Event
  .where(complaints: true, customer_account_id: [@customer_account_id], customer: @customer.id)
  .order('id desc')
  .limit(10)
```

Your refactor ignores the `OR` clause in the condition; you've written this as 3 `AND` clauses instead.

I *think* this can be written as something like:

```
Event.where(customer_account_id: [@customer_account_id])
  .or(Event.where(customer: @customer.id))
  .merge(Event.where(complaints: true))
  .order('id desc')
  .limit(10)
```

...Or something like that. Check the generated SQL in both cases.

Comment: Instead of using both `.include` and `.references` you can use `.eager_load`. `includes` actually delegates to `.eager_load` when you use `references` or reference the table in the where clause.

Comment: There is also the wierd `.push_if(@customer.contacts.to_a.map(&:id), @customer.contacts.present?)` - which adds the OR clause conditionally. I don't really get the point here though as `WHERE x IN (empty)` is logically the same.

Comment: @max Yes, true, I was keeping to a like-for-like implementation initially, but I think that's equivalent/better. As for the `push_if`, I think this is just a workaround for the fact that in the legacy implementation, this line: `contact_or = ' OR contact_id IN(?) ' if  @customer.contacts.present?` meant that the number of parameters (hence the **`push_if`**) for the `where` clause varied. It's an ugly implementation for sure.

Comment: I've added an update to the question @TomLord

Comment: Actually I'm really not sure on my answer for example 2 there, looking at it again. This is super difficult to follow. My overall answer remains the same though: **CHECK THE GENERATED SQL!!!** to see if your old and new implementations are doing the same thing.